# libffi doesn't pass the validation when creating a cocoapod

Tags: cocoapods, libffi

I recently try to create a cocoapod which includes only one third party library"BlocksKit".

When I use the "pod spec lint" to validate the podspec file, it failed. It seems there are some problems related to the library "libffi" which is used by the "BlocksKit" framework.

Below is the error message:

```
ricols-MacBook-Pro:MyPodExample ricolwang$ pod spec lint MyPodExample.podspec 

 -> MyPodExample (0.0.1)

    - ERROR | [xcodebuild]  libffi/ios/include/ffi_common.h:77:1: error: unknown type name 'ffi_status'

    - ERROR | [xcodebuild]  libffi/ios/include/ffi_common.h:77:33: error: unknown type name 'ffi_cif'

    - ERROR | [xcodebuild]  libffi/ios/include/ffi_common.h:78:1: error: unknown type name 'ffi_status'

    - ERROR | [xcodebuild]  libffi/ios/include/ffi_common.h:78:37: error: unknown type name 'ffi_cif'

    - ERROR | [xcodebuild]  libffi/ios/include/ffi_common.h:84:3: error: unknown type name 'ffi_cif'

    - ERROR | [iOS] [xcodebuild]  libffi/ios/src/debug.c:50:20: error: unknown type name 'ffi_type'

Analyzed 1 podspec.

[!] The spec did not pass validation.

ricols-MacBook-Pro:MyPodExample ricolwang$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update to latest version. As for now it's 2.2.3. libffi has been removed from BlocksKit due to lack of support for 64bit.